# Problems scaling to mobile and small screens in general

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I've recently deployed my first ever website and on my wide screen 1920x1080 monitor everything looks fantastic. However, things start to get really weird on 13" laptop screens, tablets and mobiles. I've been analysing my code and a few development tools such as googles and bootstraps recommendations for mobile and I just can't quite seem to understand **what** it is in my code that needs fixing.

On mobile, it's possible to scroll across all the way to the right to parts of the website that shouldn't even exist, just scrolling over to white space. I've managed to remove the navbar for mobile - a start, but honestly, I feel a bit lost/overwhelmed and can't seem to find the root cause of this issue.

Here is my website: -redacted-

and -redacted- is my github repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your using fixed width's for the elements on your page.

E.g. for the class `.container` you specified a width of `970px`. Try using percentages, like so:

```
.container {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto; //to center it
}
```

You can basically take this solution and apply it to the other issues on your page, like the header.

Also note:

You should also look into **media queries**, that would enable you to keep the page as it is for large screens and only change it for smaller screens, defining, e.g., a max-width:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
//anything you want for screens below a width of 800px
}
```

EDIT:

I understand you are using Bootstrap - in that case you would need to entirely delete all statements that are overriding Bootstrap's default configurations.

Anyway, keep the upper recommendations in mind for future CSS coding.

Comment: He is using Bootstrap to provide the `.container` class, the problem is that he is overriding what it is meant to do.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i've changed a few of the css rules to be % based and theyre already acting a lot more responsive.

Comment: @Zaidra: glad to hear! :)

Comment: @Mortimer Despite changing the width and height properites, the page still isnt properly scaling. The text doesnt change in scale at all, and the navbar just falls to pieces.

Comment: By changing rules like this you are likely further messing with how Bootstrap is meant to work, I'm afraid. Mortimer is right that percentage sizing is good for what you need in general, but when you are using the Bootstrap framework your best starting point would be to follow its rules and conventions. Subverting it further by changing rules you've already changed to work via percentages is just piling more cards on a house built out of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have this rule in your CSS, which is ruining the responsive effect the `.container` class from Bootstrap is supposed to have (overriding the media-query-set width it should be using, and indeed is using in other parts of the page):

```
.myskills .container {
  width: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}
```

Setting a fixed width, in this example, being the problem.

There may be more examples of things like this on the site, so I'd advise removing all examples of this that you can find.

In general I wouldn't advocate overriding Bootstrap CSS classes without being very sure why you need to do so, particularly the structural elements like `.container`, `.row` and `.col-xx-x` classes.

Comment: Thank you, you're absolutely right. I didn't realise I was shooting myself in the foot this way!

Comment: Hello, i've been working on the code some more and the site seems to scale to mobile except for one core part - the text! I can't seem to figure out why but the text is massive while everything else scales nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You have set your containers width with `px`.

Try to change them with `%` or directly **erase those px measures**.

Bootstrap `containers` adjust themselves to the correct width they need.